# why isn't the useWatch defaultValue not being overwritten?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have the following code in one file and I am watching 2 fields to see if 1 or both are undefined and registering that boolean:

```
const field1 = useWatch({ control, name: 'field1Name', defaultValue: field1DefaultValue });
const field2 = useWatch({ control, name: 'field2Name', defaultValue: field2DefaultValue });
register('undefinedFields', { value: field1 || field2 });
```

In another file I am watching 'undefinedFields' to get that boolean

```
const areThereUndefinedFields = useWatch({ control, name: 'undefinedFields', defaultValue: true});
```

I set the defaultValue to be true because leaving out the default value causes the const 'areThereUndefinedFields' to always be undefined.
When both 'field1' and 'field2' are false, 'undefinedFields' has a value of false, but the value of 'areThereUndefinedFields' does not change to false. I am confused as to why the value of 'areThereUndefinedFields' is always the defaultValue and doesn't change?

Comment: Unrelated: why use a ternary operator with `true` and `false` in each branch when the expression `... === undefined` already returns a boolean?

Comment: @GuerricP It was my first reaction when looking at the code! 

Comment: @GuerricP thanks for pointing that out! I totally forgot that when something is undefined it will return false